# Report Builder 3.0 date parameter with specific time

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an end-of-shift report I'm trying to automate. I am trying to create a preset start and end date parameter for shift schedules. StartDate: (AM Shift = Today @ 06:00) & (PM Shift = Yesterday @ 18:00) EndDate: (AM Shift = Today @ 18:00) & (PM Shift = Today @ 06:00). Since there are two shifts, I don't want to hardcode my date/time range into my query. And since the shifts are unchanging, I don't want to just set the calendar and give the user options to change the date/time range.
I changed the parameter type to date/time and am attempting to fix the expression for available values to these predetermined date/times. Because I do not want the user to change the date/time range and only select the specific shift schedule, I am having difficulty getting the expression to work with both date and time separately. All of the below do not work, but are what I've tried. Examples specifically for **Yesterday at 18:00**.Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

- =CDate(DateAdd("d",-1,Today()) + "18:00:00.000")
- =DateAdd("d",-1,Today()) + "18:00:00.000"
- =DateAdd("d",-1,Today()) & "18:00:00.000"
- =Format((DateAdd("d",-1,Today())),"MM/dd/yyyy 18:00:00.000")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use CDate like this, it's easier to start with a date and then add or subtract from it.

for example

```
=DateAdd("H", 18, DateAdd("D", -1, Today()))
```

The second `DateAdd` gives us Yesterday and because we use `Today()` rather than `Now()` it gives us yesterday at time 00:00:000, now all we have to do is add 18 hours to it and we get yesterday at 6pm

If you want to base this on a parameter (called `shift` in this example) then you can do something like this

Start -

```
=IIF(Parameters!shift.Value = "AM" , 
    DateAdd("H",  6, Today()), 
    DateAdd("H", 18, DateAdd("D", -1, Today()))
    )
```

End -

```
=IIF(Parameters!shift.Value = "AM", 
    DateAdd("H", 18, Today), 
    DateAdd("H", 6, Today)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I used and it worked perfectly: =DateAdd("H",18,DateAdd("d",-1,Today())) You were right, I had to add the date and time not add the date and tell the time.